# Definir tamanho do Popup - GridLookUpEdit

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridlookupedit

Alguem saberia como diminuir o popup, apresentado pelo controle `GridLookUpEdit` da DevExpress?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deverá tratar o evento `QueryPopup` e modificar o tamanho do popup atribuindo um `Size` com os valores que desejar:

```
private void gridLookUpEdit1_QueryPopUp(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
    GridLookUpEdit editor = (GridLookUpEdit)sender;
    RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit properties = editor.Properties;
    // mudando apenas a largura, mas não a altura, por exemplo:
    properties.PopupFormSize = new Size(500, properties.PopupFormSize.Height);
}
```